# Convert interface to int64 does not work as expected

Tags: go, casting, timestamp

I am trying to write a method to convert epoch timestamps to `int64` values, but the method may get multiple data types; e.g. `int64`, `int`, `string`. I have following piece of code for it:

```
package main

import (
    "fmt"
)

func test(t interface{}) {
    tInt64, ok := t.(int64)
    fmt.Println("initial value:", t)
    fmt.Printf("initial type: %T\n", t)
    fmt.Println("casting status:", ok)
    fmt.Println("converted:", tInt64)
}

func main() {
    t := 1606800000
    tStr := "1606800000"

    test(t)
    test(tStr)

}
```

I expect it to successfully convert both `t` and `tStr` variables to `int64`; but, here's the result:

```
initial value: 1606800000
initial type: int
casting status: false
converted: 0
initial value: 1606800000
initial type: string
casting status: false
converted: 0
```

I don't know if it's related or not; but I executed the code with three version of golang compiler: `1.13`, `1.14` and `1.15`. All had same output.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Go does not have the requested feature. Write some code like this:

```
func test(t interface{}) (int64, error) {
    switch t := t.(type) {   // This is a type switch.
    case int64:
        return t, nil        // All done if we got an int64.
    case int:
        return int64(t), nil // This uses a conversion from int to int64
    case string:
        return strconv.ParseInt(t, 10, 64)
    default:
        return 0, fmt.Errorf("type %T not supported", t)
    }
}
```

[Run this code on the GoLango Playgroundo](https://play.golang.org/p/tjeyMvirywz)

Comment: I did the same after @cerise-limón said and I was going to post it myself. Bu I think I should approve yours now. :-)